# Solving integral equations

Tags: calculus

For solving the integral equation:

$$f(-x)=x+\int_{0}^{x} \sin t f(x-t) dt.$$

I assume two cases: (a) $f(x)=f(-x)$ and (b) $f(x)=-f(-x).$ Since

$$\int_{0}^{x} \sin t f(x-t) dt=\int_{0}^{x} \sin (x-t) f(t) dt$$

we may have:

(a) $f(x)=x+\int_{0}^{x} \sin (x-t) f(t)dt.$

Then, we may use Laplace transformation as:

$F(s)= \frac{1}{s^2}+ \frac{F(s)}{s^2+1}$

Similarly for (b). Am I right?

Comment: Also: why can you limit yourself to those two cases?

Comment: There may be case like $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ which doesn't fall into these two cases